# AVAssetRescourceLoader shouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge only triggers using the Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I am using the AVARLDelegateDemo Example supplied by Apple it is suppose to stream m3u8 video. My Stream is HSL HTTPBasicAuth user and password. I added the:

```
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)authenticationChallenge
```

on the APLCustomDelegate its seems to work great when using the simulator the videos shows up and the shouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge is called.

the problem is when I deploy it to a device it displays a 401 ERROR
and after doing some testing it looks like the shouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge is not being called

BTW: I have Allow Arbitrary Loads: YES

[LINK TO APPLE SOURCE](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/sc1791/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014357-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: What version of iOS is this running on? If it's iOS 9, have you added the endpoints to App Transport Security Settings in the plist?

Comment: Hi Luke thanks, It is running tvOS 9.2, I have not added the endpoints but how would that look like? I only added the Allow Arbitrary Loads YES